# how to terminate PVC conduit at a building

Tags: wiring, conduit

I want to extend a wired cat5 network to a building 50ft away using fiber in conduit, and media converters on either end. Both buildings are single family homes on slab foundations. How is that conduit usually terminated at the buildings? Would I use an elbow with removable cover (for ease of fishing)? Or some kind of weatherproof box?

Comment: If you haven't already bought them, for some odd economic reason, small switches with 1 or 2 SFP or XFP ports and 4-5 copper ports are generally less expensive than "media converters" (a two port switch with one SFP/XFP and one copper.)

Comment: Point to point wireless link is an option which may suit here - depends what's in the way (like trees)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The elbows with removable covers (conduit bodies) are the normal way to pass conduit through an external wall.

Trying to waterproof buried conduit is a losing game, unless you live in a desert there will be water inside there fairly soon.

Comment: Use waterproof/exterior-rated fiber cable. Exterior conduit is defined as wet, and usually is.

Comment: You may want to use a larger LB/LL/LR than your conduit is, with an adapter, to make the corner less tight. Or get reduced bend radius fiber and you won't need to. LBs are normally easiest for this.

Comment: Make sure that you leave plenty of slack in the LB and use an expansion fitting ([like this example](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Kraloy-1-2-in-PVC-Conduit-Expansion-Coupling-91-Hub-93/5001212887)) between the buried part of the conduit and the LB. This will allow the conduit to frost heave independently of the building, which shouldn't be moving.